# Pad outgoing messages

Tags: python, xchat2

I can't quite figure out how to pad a message that I send. Basically.. I want to pad the message to the max 512 chars as defined in the RFC.

I understand that a message being sent by the user will contain user!user@hostname privmsg #chan (or other_user): text text text \r\n.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pad a string you can use the functions [`ljust`, `center` or `rjust`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods), respectively:

```py
print "Hello, " + "world".ljust(10) + "!"
print "Hello, " + "world".center(10) + "!"
print "Hello, " + "world".rjust(10) + "!"
```

Output ([Try it](http://ideone.com/Wih6IG)):

```
Hello, world     !
Hello,   world   !
Hello,      world!
```

All three functions have an optional second argument `fillchar` which lets you specify the character that is used to fill up the additional space.

Comment: Basically all I would need to do is determine original string length as X, use one of the pad functions "ljust(512-X)" ?? or something similar? I am also unsure as to how I would implement this as an xchat2 plugin/script.

Comment: As can be seen from the example, you do not need to determine ```len(X)```, since the argument ```10``` is already the total width. You should have a look into [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods) if in doubt.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question: I have no idea! You should give a little more information about what you are trying to achieve and what code you have so far. I thought it's about strings (as the title indicates). So maybe you even open a new question to attract peoples attention that are more into xchat2.